# Hydrate and Constructors in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

When instancing an object from a SQL database, I read I should use a `hydrate()` function to populate my objects rather than the constructor directly.

Is there differences between the codes below ?

**With hydrate() :**

```
class User {

    // attributes ...

    public function __construct(array $data = array()) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this->hydrate($data);
            }
    }
    public function hydrate(array $data) {
       foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          // One gets the setter's name matching the attribute.
          $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);

          // If the matching setter exists
          if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
             // One calls the setter.
             $this->$method($value);
          }
       }
    }
   // Getters/Setters and methods ...
}
```

**Into constructor directly :**

```
class User {

        // attributes ...

    public function __construct(array $data = array()) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                   // One gets the setter's name matching the attribute.
                   $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);

                   // If the matching setter exists
                   if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                     // One calls the setter.
                     $this->$method($value);
                   }
                }
            }
    }
   // Getters/Setters and methods ...
}
```

Comment: Pretty opinion based but it will keep your constructor clean and allow you to abstract hydrate to an abstract class or trait.

Comment: If you have a function then you can call it after you've constructed the object as well in case you need to. It's useful if you what to test specific functionality with various inputs without creating a bunch of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have classes with many attributes, with each attribute possessing it's own setter with specific checks, this is a useful way of calling them all, not one by one.

It's second purpose is if you need to reuse your object (let's say to perform test) with new values. You won't have to reconstruct a new one (or each of the setters), just recall hydrate and your class attributes will be updated.

Here is a basic example:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    protected $titre;
    protected $date;
    protected ...
    // And so on

    public function __construct($value = array())
    {
        if(!empty($value))
            $this->hydrate($value);
    }

    public function hydrate($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $attribut => $value) {
            $method = 'set'.str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $attribut)));
            if (is_callable(array($this, $method))) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        // Do specific check
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setDate($date)
    {
        // Do specific check
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}

$test = new Test(array("title" => "helloworld", ...));
// Manipulate the $test var and change stuff
...
$new_values = array("title" => "Hello, I am back", ...);
$test->hydrate($new_values);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah sure I got this but I wonder why I should not put the code directly into the construct function? Just for tidiness purpose ?

Comment: Imagine you have many attributes and you have to perform custom checks on them, your constructor will be filled with non-sense and later on, if you need to change these values, you can't recheck them. This way with the hydrate function, you keep everything clean and tidy and you can recall the hydrate function again with new values to populate the fields

Comment: I have updated my question if it can helps showing what I ask

Comment: @Will I edited my answer to better help you understand hydrate purpose

Comment: What's the point of checking for `empty`? If the array is empty the `foreach` will exit immediately anyway... Is this just a micro optimization to avoid a method call?